# How to save one password for all users without hashing?

Tags: passwords, hash

I am working on a plugin for site A that logs in to an external site B.

The plugin needs to store the password to site B, but I can't use hashing because I need to send the login information to B. I can't store additional information on the user's device either, because there is only one password for all users of site A. The admin sets the password and the script always connects to site B using that information for every user. So it has to be accessible 24/7. Plus the plugin should be usable by others also using their personal versions of site A. So it would be good, if the administrator doesn't have to do much/anything at all to configure the plugin and the password could just be set easily.

I read about a solution using a VM, but that's just not applicable here.
Is there any way to save the password without creating security issues?

Comment: Does Site B have any alternative methods of login, such as an OAuth token or similar? These are quite common for sites intended for use by other sites on behalf of users, and avoids the password issue.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any alternative login methods.

Comment: Can you expand what you mean by _"Plus the plugin should be usable by others also using their personal versions of site A."_? What does _"personal version of site A"_ mean?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "plugin"? Is this a browser extension? Is this some javascript that runs in the user's browser? Is this an extension to the web server that runs on the server? The answer will vary depending.

Comment: You do not give enough information on what is *site A* and how it connects to site B. But if site A has to provide a unique password to site B, this this password has to exist in readable form on the machine, and must be accessible to the application. Depending on the system and application type, that may or not imply readable by users. Please add precisions if you need a more detailed answer.

Comment: Have you considered federated sign-on (like SAML or openID)? Most of the sites support this facility which allows you to login to Site B from Site A after you have authenticated in Site A.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding of your situation:

- Site A is internal and each user has their own account.
- Site B is external where the institution has one user-account that everybody shares (I'm picturing access to academic journals or something).
- You want to make a plugin for Site A that pulls content from Site B into Site A -- and therefore needs to automatically log into Site B.

Correct?

---

Naively I see a number of options:

1. Ask the user to type in Site B's password every time you need it, that way you're not storing it anywhere.
2. Ask the user to type in Site B's password once and store it in their local browser cache. This is less secure in exchange for more convenience.
3. The admin embed the username / password to Site B in the source code for the plugin. This is the highest convenience, but the least secure because someone could reverse-engineer the password out of the plugin (how hard this is depends on which language the plugin is in, whether the plugin runs on a server or in the browser, etc).

Basically, either you store the credentials in the plugin, or you don't.

A more complex option:

- How does Site B's authentication mechanism work? I assume when you provide the correct username / password, Site B returns you some sort of authentication token? Is it possible to stand up a small server that holds the credentials, logs in for you, and returns you the token?

Like this:

```
Browser plugin --log-me-in-plz--> your server --[username/pass]--> Site B

               <-- auth-token--                <--auth-token--
```

---

To be honest, it sounds like your real issue here is that everyone shares one username/password. You are trying to secure something that's weak to begin with.

Have you talked to the people who run Site B? Is this the way they intend you to use their site? Do they have any other auth mechanisms besides this shared username/password? Can you get each user their own account?

Your situation seems a bit like being asked to install security systems in a mansion, but being told by the owner that they never lock the doors and they don't want to have to type in any security codes. The correct answer is to go back to the customer and say "I can't secure this, anything I do will be security theatre at best".

Given this, maybe your organization will be ok with option 3 above and just accept that if someone is determined enough, they can get the password out of the script.

Comment: Yes, that's basically how it should work. I'll get a little more into detail:

Comment: We have a learning management system and every user has their own account. We want to connect to a system that checks for plagiarsm in files students upload to the LMS. That's where the plugin comes in. It connects to the external site via php xmlrpc. So no user has the password for the external site and that's as it should be, because else everyone could see all the files that are on the system. 
As the plagiarism site offers connection via xmlrpc, I think it's the intended use. 

Thx for your input. I think the method with the intermediate server could work.

Comment: @Sanshi Well that raises extra questions: you want to reach out to the plagiarism server from your LMS server after the file has been uploaded -- not from the browser before the file is uploaded. Reason: if you do it in the browser then a savvy user could disable that check in the javascript and bypass the plagiarism check.

Comment: Yes, that's how it works. It gets uploaded to our server and from there it is sent to the plagiarism server.

Comment: @Sanshi So then I really don't understand your question. Why can't you just store it the database like you would any other sensitive info?

Comment: But other sensitive information is usually stored as a hash and not as plain text.

Comment: @Sanshi What about sensitive information that you need to retrieve (aka "Personal Identifiable Information, PII") like addresses, credit card numbers, etc? I assume you have some sort of encryption in your database for this information?

Comment: Basically I think the important thing here is that your end-users who use your web site can't  ever see the password for the plagiarism server. If logging in to the plagiarism server is happening from your server (not from the users' browsers) then you're good and I don't think it really matters how you save it to disk. Do whatever you do for other information in your database.